# OpenGL version issues

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I am using OpenGL and having some issues with the version I am using. When I check my version using `glGetString(GL_VERSION)`, I get **"4.2.0 - Build 10.18.10.3574"**. I have following questions:

1. In one approach I am using fixed pipeline for rendering, but I know that support for fixed pipeline was removed from OpenGL 3.1, so how is my code working with 4.2? I am using API like `glTranslatef()`, `glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)`. I think these all are deprecated and work only with OpenGL 1.1. So how is the code working when I get the context string as OpenGL 4.2? I think I must be using OpenGL 1.1, but then why context version comes as 4.2?
2. When I use shaders, I am creating the 3.1 or higher context using following code. The shaders I am using are old shaders which are compatible with OpenGL 2.0 and have keywords like "attribute", "varying" and should not work with OpenGL 3.1 or higher. I should need to update my shaders to OpenGLSL 3.1 like using "in", "out" etc. Also there are deprecated things like `GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT`, `glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)`. I think these things have been deprecated from OpenGL 3.0. So how are these things working with GL context 3.1 and higher?

Code to create context 3.1 or higher

```
if ( 0 == (m_tempContext = ::wglCreateContext( m_pDC->GetSafeHdc() ) ) )
{
    AfxMessageBox(_T("wglCreateContext failed."));
    return FALSE;
}
if ( FALSE == ::wglMakeCurrent( m_pDC->GetSafeHdc(), m_tempContext ) )
{
    AfxMessageBox(_T("wglMakeCurrent failed."));
    return FALSE;
}
int attribs[] =
{
    WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
    WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 1,
    WGL_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB, 0,
    0
};

if(wglewIsSupported("WGL_ARB_create_context") == 1)
{
m_hRC = wglCreateContextAttribsARB(m_pDC->GetSafeHdc() ,0, attribs);
wglMakeCurrent(NULL,NULL);
wglDeleteContext(m_tempContext);
wglMakeCurrent( m_pDC->GetSafeHdc(), m_hRC);
}
```

One of the shaders I am using

```
const GLchar* vertexShaderCode =                                        \
    "attribute vec4 a_Position;                                \n"  \
    "attribute vec2 a_TexCoordinate;                           \n"  \
    "uniform mat4 u_MVPMatrix;                                 \n"  \
    "varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;                             \n"  \
                                                                    \
    "void main()                                               \n"  \
    "{                                                         \n"  \
    "    gl_Position = u_MVPMatrix * a_Position;               \n"  \
    "    v_TexCoordinate = a_TexCoordinate;                    \n"  \
    "}                                                         \n"; \
                                                                    \
const GLchar* fragmentShaderCode =                                      \
    "#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable            \n" \
    "#ifdef GL_ES                                               \n" \
    "precision highp float;                                     \n" \
    "#endif                                                     \n" \
    "varying vec2       v_TexCoordinate;                        \n" \
    "uniform sampler2D  u_Texture;                              \n" \
    "uniform vec4       u_Color;                                \n" \
    "uniform float      u_InsideCutoff;                         \n" \
    "uniform float      u_OutsideCutoff;                        \n" \
    "uniform float      u_TextureSize;                          \n" \
                                                                    \
    "void main()                                                \n" \
    "{                                                          \n" \
    "   vec4 distance = texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoordinate);  \n" \
    "   vec3 color;                                             \n" \
    "   float ic;                                               \n" \
    "   float oc;                                               \n" \
    "   float alpha;                                            \n" \
                                                                    \
    "   vec4  duvdxy  = vec4(dFdx(v_TexCoordinate), dFdy(v_TexCoordinate));              \n" \
    "   float pixSize = length(u_TextureSize*duvdxy);                                    \n" \
    "   ic = 0.5 + u_InsideCutoff*pixSize;                                               \n" \
    "   oc = 0.5 + u_OutsideCutoff*pixSize;                                              \n" \
    "   alpha = (clamp(distance.r,oc,ic) - oc)/(ic-oc);                                  \n" \
    "   alpha *= u_Color.a;                                                              \n" \
    "   color = u_Color.rgb;                                                             \n" \
    "   gl_FragColor = vec4(color, alpha);                                               \n" \
    "}                                                                                   \n";
```

Basically I need to update my shaders and other code to work with OpenGL 3.1 and higher context. I have been out of touch with OpenGL for some time now. So sorry if its too naive question

Comment: My understanding is that 3.1 and earlier can still provide access to 'deprecated' functionality. It is only as of 3.2 that the 'core' and 'compatibility' profiles are introduced.

Comment: yes actually you are right. If I create a context upto 3.1, things work but if I try to make context 3.2 or higher, I get blank window. I have changed my shaders to make them compatible with 3.2. But these shaders are also working well will 3.1, 2.0 context. Is it expected? like can a openglsl 3.0 shader work with opengl 2.0 context ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenGL 3.1 did indeed remove the previously deprecated functionality. However, 3.1 also introduced the `ARB_compatibility` extension, which effectively brings it all back. If you ask for version 3.1, your *implementation* gets to decide whether you can also use the removed functionality or not.

For versions 3.2 or greater, OpenGL was split into the [core and compatibility profiles](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_And_Compatibility_in_Contexts). If you want the compatibility profile with `wgl/glXCreateContextAttribsARB`, you must explicitly ask for it with by setting `CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB` to `CONTEXT_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE_BIT_ARB`. Otherwise, the core profile is assumed when you use ARB_create_context_attrib for 3.2 or above.

Note that if you use `wglCreateContext`, you will always get a compatibility profile (or an OpenGL version before the core/compatibility distinction).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped a lot. I still cant understand one thing. Why is my fixed pipeline implementation working with 4.2 context ?  or it something like wglCreateContext( m_pDC->GetSafeHdc() ) always create 2.1 context, but when  I get glGetString(GL_VERSION) it returns 4.2 ?